# Is there a likely / common cause of a LNK2001 unresolved external symbol error when not using any outside libraries?

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to create a new instance of a class, however I am receiving a LNK2001 unresolved external symbol error when I attempt to compile my code.

As far as I can tell I have written and included the class in exactly the same manner as I included another class, in both cases -

```
#include "class.h"      // In main.cpp 

class Class {           // In class.h
   private: 
       // etc. 
   public:         
       Class(); 
       ~Class(); 
       // etc.
}; 

#include "class.h"      // In class.cpp
```

Is there a common / likely cause of these errors, or a good way I might go about finding the source of the issue?

**Edit:** The error is

> "Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Max
>   __cdecl max(void)" (?max@@YA?AVMax@@XZ) referenced in function _main  main.obj    Racing "

**Edit:** In both cases, a class is implemented across a .h and a .cpp file included in a project. The error is only appearing with one class.

Comment: The error's not in the code you're showing - you need to post the code or it's very hard to help you.

Comment: To what external symbol is it referring?

Comment: are you trying to link from another project? does you linker know where to find the .obj file? the static/dynamic library?

Comment: I've added the full error text :) 

I am not trying to link from another project.

Comment: did you implement Class::max(void) ?

Comment: There is no Class::max(void) - the class is called Max. 

There is a Max::Max() constructor which is implemented.

Comment: (The instance of Max in main.cpp is named max, upon changing the name of the instance of Max, max in the error changes to name_of_instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you have written this:

```
Max max();
```

What you intended was to declare a variable `max` of type `Max`.

C++ thinks you intend to declare a function `max` which returns an object of type `Max`. This is what it is looking for.

If you just say this:

```
Max max;
```

The issue will go away.

**Edit:** This only occurs with constructors which take no arguments. If the constructor takes arguments, C++ can see from the parameters (which will be rvalues, e.g. constants or expressions) that it is an instantiation of the class not a function declaration.

```
Max max(5);  // Clearly cannot be a function, because 5 is an rvalue
```

Or

```
Max max(int); // Clearly cannot be an instantiation, because int is a type
```

But if the constructor takes no arguments, to distinguish between them, you have to drop the brackets if you are instantiating.

Comment: Ah wow thanks, I hadn't realised that issue came up with empty constructors! Thanks very much :)